# What is the difference between romance and adventure?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The word, "romance" in my question refers to the cases where "romance" is used in the following examples:

1. There's a touch of **romance** about the sea, given that seafaring created the economies and history of the region before the skies took over as the main means of transport.
2. Oh, and there is the fact that I no longer travel the world attending academic conferences in search of adventure and **romance**.

> To put simply, I would like to know more about the pronounced
>   differences between "romance" and "adventure". Any examples to
>   illustrate the same will also be greatly appreciated.

Examples are referred from: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/romance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definitions seem to be pretty distinct:

> [**Romance**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/romance) (n): *A quality or feeling of mystery, excitement, and remoteness from everyday life.*
>
> **[Adventure](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adventure)** (n): *An unusual and exciting or daring experience; A reckless or potentially hazardous action or enterprise.*

*Romance* deals with something that has the attraction of being *pleasantly unusual* and *mysterious*, something very different from the kind of thing you might do every day.  Often this involves some measure of risk -- not necessarily *physical* risk, but rather the courage to try something entirely new, to "wander off the beaten path."

*Adventure*, on the other hand, often has some qualities of romance, but combined with the element of *physical* risk.  Most adventures contain some chance of injury or death.

So, for Americans, traveling around Europe on a bus tour might be considered *romantic*, because we get to see many famous places and have unusual experiences ... but not necessarily *adventurous*, because there's little danger.  It's considerably more *adventurous* to backpack around Europe by train, staying in youth hostels and cheap hotels, because then there is much less control over what might happen.

On the other hand, enlisting in the military is considered *adventurous* but not particularly *romantic* (depending on your point of view) because most imagine the experience will be unusual but not *pleasant*, and there may be considerable physical risk.

Comment: "Adventure, on the other hand, often has some qualities of romance, but combined with the element of physical risk."
This makes sense. Thank you!